# How to implement an authenticated es 7 decorator with babel for my js service module

Tags: javascript, node.js, decorator, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I'm using babel with decorator stage:0 support in my flux fluxible js project, and I want to use an authenticated decorator for my service api modules to check for a valid user session.

Googling around, there seems to be several posts that explain different variations but couldn't find one definitive docs or instructionals.

Here's what I tried so far, I know that my parameters for the authenticated function are incorrect, and not sure if I need to implement a class for my module rather than just using the exports object.

The part that I couldn't find the docs for is how to implement the decorator itself - in this case something that takes the req parameter the decorated function will receive and checking it.

```
// how do I change this method so that it can be implemented as a decorator
function checkAuthenticated(req) {

    if (!req.session || !req.session.username)
    {
        throw new Error('unauthenticated');
    }
}

module.exports = {
    @checkAuthenticated
    read: function(req, resource, params, serviceConfig, callback) {
        //@authenticated decorator should allow me to move this out of this here
        //checkAuthenticated(req);
        if (resource === 'product.search') {
            var keyword = params.text;
            if (!keyword || keyword.length === 0) {
                return callback('empty param', null);
            } else {
                searchProducts(keyword, callback);
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: The decorator would have your read method as an argument, not the request, as it stands now. How you had it before (the commented out part) would work correctly, what was wrong with that?

Comment: the commented out section works fine - but I was curious about learning how to use decorators so was using this as a learning possibility.  Using the decorator how can I get the req parameter from the read method into the check function?

Comment: See my answer, it should work. @decorator is simply shorthand for decorator(methodToDecorate)

Comment: I have it in a class property and console.logging the arguments to the decorator shows this {"0":{},"1":"read","2":{"enumerable":false,"configurable":true,"writable":true}}

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the signature is different for classes (how I've used them) versus class properties. See my updated answer and jsbin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Http{
  @checkAuthenticated
  read(req, resource, params, serviceConfig, callback) {
    if (resource === 'product.search') {
      var keyword = params.text;
      if (!keyword || keyword.length === 0) {
        return callback('empty param', null);
      } else {
        this.searchProducts(keyword, callback);
      }
    }
  }

  searchProducts(keyword, callback) {
    callback(null, 'worked');
  }
}

function checkAuthenticated(target, key, descriptor) {
    return {
      ...descriptor,
      value: function(){
        console.log(arguments);
        const req = arguments[0];
        if (!req.session || !req.session.username) {
            throw new Error('unauthenticated');
        }
        return descriptor.value.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    };
}

let h = new Http();

h.read(
  { session: { username: 'user' } },
  'product.search',
  { text: 'my keywords' },
  null,
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) return alert(err);
    return alert(result);
  }
);
```

See jsbin http://jsbin.com/yebito/edit?js,console,output

Comment: just tried this and got the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined /node_modules/fluxible-plugin-fetchr/node_modules/fetchr/libs/fetcher.js:181
    service[op].apply(service, args);`

Comment: it looks like the signature for the decorator function is actually expecting (target, key, descriptor) rather than a function (fn) in my case